# Property names expressed as plain string text

Tags: vb.net, properties

I have a class which exposes properties.
The values of these properties are pulled/pushed from a third party document, accessed via a set of Get/Set functions which parse the document looking for the given PropertyName string:

```
Public Property MyProperty As String
    Return GetDocVariableValue("MyProperty")
End Get
Set(value As String)
    SetDocVariableValue("MyProperty", value)
End Set
End Property
```

My object has dozens of these properties. I am looking for a clean way to ensure each "MyProperty": (i) is proof against misspellings, and (ii) will survive maintenance.

I thought of several options:

1. Replace `"MyProperty"` by `NameOf(MyProperty)`: this fully complies with (i), but puts (ii) at risk if someone changes the property name: the variable value will be stored in a different slot which will create backwards compatibility issues (with documents edited/saved before the software update).
2. Replace `"MyProperty"` by `CstMyProperty`, and add `Private Const CstMyProperty As String = "MyProperty"`: this reduces the risk identified by (i), and ensures backwards compatibility.
3. Replace `"MyProperty"` by `Properties.MyProperty`, and add

.

```
Enum Properties
    MyProperty
    AnotherProperty
    ...
End Enum
Private PropertiesNames as Ilist(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {"MyProperty", "AnotherProperty", ...}
```

`GetDocVariableValue()` and `SetDocVariableValue` now take the enumeration as an input, and rely on `PropertiesNames` to fetch the string.

I do like the third option because it centralizes the property names all in one place. But my object inherits from a base class which is where the `GetDocVariableValue()` and `SetDocVariableValue` functions are declared, as well as where a few basic properties are exposed, relying on the same principle. So ideally in the child class I would have "extended" the enumeration of the base class, but that is not possible, so I end up using a separate enumeration, which means rewriting the `GetDocVariableValue()` and `SetDocVariableValue` functions so that they accept the child enumeration as an input, which definitely adds a layer of complexity for just little gain.

At the moment I go with 2., but I was wondering if there were other alternatives I may have not though of yet?

Comment: If you change `MyProperty`, `nameof(Me.MyProperty)` will show an error. You won't be able to build your app. Since it's what the property gets/sets, it looks like it should give a clue that something might be wrong. Documentation helps. The enumerator is not bad either. Documentation helps to understand what's for. Nothing will help if one doesn't read the Docs.

Comment: When I change a field I always use the rename feature, which updates all references, including `NameOf()`. I expect everyone to do the same, and that is  probably the sole purpose of `NameOf()`.

Comment: If you add a `'''Summary` to the properties that explain what's for and its usage, probably won't be changed. I find it difficult to believe that someone can change Properties of an application/library as it was nothing. Documentation helps, anyway. Are you also afraid that someone, mindlessly, will change the enumerators, as it was nothing? You can use Application Settings, JSON/XML files, a database etc. to store values and return what's appropriate.